# Reuse of a capture in grok

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok

I am trying to reuse a capture in grok plugin from Logstash. 
I have this logfile

```
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID1> DEVICE0 START_THREAD THREAD_ID(B01234)
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID1> DEVICE1 START_THREAD THREAD_ID(B12345)
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID1> DEVICE2 START_THREAD THREAD_ID(A12345)
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID2> DEVICE1 PROCESSING SPOOLID 100 
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID2> DEVICE2 PROCESSING SPOOLID 101
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID2> DEVICE2 PROCESSING SPOOLID 101
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID2> DEVICE1 PROCESSING SPOOLID 100
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID4> DEVICE1 SPOOLID 100 PROCESSED
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID4> DEVICE2 SPOOLID 101 PROCESSED
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID3> DEVICE2 STOP_THREAD THREAD_ID(B12345) 
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID3> DEVICE2 STOP_THREAD THREAD_ID(A12345)
30 Jul 2019 09:56:28 <ID1> DEVICE2 START_THREAD THREAD_ID(A23456)
30 Jul 2019 09:56:29 <ID2> DEVICE2 PROCESSING SPOOLID 102
30 Jul 2019 09:56:29 <ID2> DEVICE2 PROCESSING SPOOLID 102
30 Jul 2019 09:56:29 <ID4> DEVICE2 SPOOLID 102 PROCESSED
30 Jul 2019 09:56:29 <ID3> DEVICE2 STOP_THREAD THREAD_ID(A23456) 
30 Jul 2019 09:56:29 <ID2> DEVICE0 PROCESSING SPOOLID 99 
30 Jul 2019 09:56:29 <ID4> DEVICE0 SPOOLID 99 PROCESSED
30 Jul 2019 09:56:29 <ID3> DEVICE0 STOP_THREAD THREAD_ID(B12345)
```

What I would like to do is to capture the DEVICE and the SPOOL_ID into one logstash event.
So far I've managed to build this Regular Expression which gives me the correct SPOOLID to the corresponding DEVICE

```
/.*?\>\s+(\b.*?\b)\s*START_THREAD.*?\1\s+SPOOLID\s+(\d+)\s+PROCESSED/ms
```

I've been trying to translate this RegEx to grok with this code

```
(?m)%{DATA}\>\s+\b%{DATA:device}\b\s*START_THREAD%{DATA}(?<device>\s+SPOOLID\s+%{NUMBER:num}\s+PROCESSED)
```

Unfortunately, I am getting the wrong SPOOLID for the corresponding device (for DEVICE0 I get the SPOOLID 100 instead of 99).
I cannot figure out what is wrong with my grok code.
Maybe someone here can find the error in my code and fix it?

Comment: Try `(?m)%{DATA}>\s+(?<aux>\b%{DATA:device}\b)\s*START_THREAD%{DATA}\k<aux>(?<device>\s+SPOOLID\s+%{NUMBER:num}\s+PROCESSED)`. `aux` group is auxiliary, but you may ignore its value.

Comment: Please post it as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that the `%{...}` groups are not actually working the same way as named capturing groups, you need to create an auxiliary named capturing group  and refer to it using the named  backreference using `\k<name>` syntax:

```
(?m)%{DATA}>\s+(?<aux>\b%{DATA:device}\b)\s*START_THREAD%{DATA}\k<aux>(?<device>\s+SPOOLID\s+%{NUMBER:num}\s+PROCESSED)
```

Note the `(?<aux>\b%{DATA:device}\b)` named group and `\k<aux>` backreference here.

See more on the [Oniguruma regex syntax](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE) here.